# Separate continuity and analyticity in one variable implies joint continuity?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, continuity, holomorphic-functions, product-space

A theorem of Hartog states that if $U \subseteq \mathbb C$ is open and $f : U \times U \to \mathbb C$ is analytic when we fix any variable ('separately analytic'), then it is continuous.

In general, it is not true that separate continuity implies joint continuity (See e.g. [Functions continuous in each variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51296): $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} : \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a counterexample).

One can show that separate continuity implies continuity in (at least) a dense $G_\delta$-set (Theorem 1.2 [in this article](https://msp.org/pjm/1974/51-2/pjm-v51-n2-p23-s.pdf)).

> If $X$ is a topological space and $U \subseteq \mathbb C$ open, what can we say about separately continuous functions $f : X \times U \to \mathbb C$ that are analytic in the second variable?
>
> Does this imply that $f$ jointly continuous, or are there counterexamples?

Let's say $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

> What if $f$ is in addition real analytic in the first variable?

---

I know that:

- $f$ is continuous in open sets where it is locally bounded, by using Cauchy's integral formula.
- In particular, if $X_0 \subseteq X$ and $f$ is continuous on $X_0 \times J$ with $J$ a smooth Jordan curve, then it is continuous on $X_0 \times $ the interior of $J$. Thus isolated discontinuities like the one of $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ cannot occur.
- An application of the Baire Category Theorem shows that for $K \subseteq X$ compact there exists an open dense subset $V \subseteq U$ such that $f$ is continuous on $K \times V$. Similarly for $L \subseteq U$ compact. See also this question: [If a function on a product space is continuous in each variable, is it locally bounded?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848410)
  We've used holomorphy here, but not enough, because the counterexample $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ satisfies the conclusions so far.

Note how we recover the dense $G_\delta$-result by letting $K$ grow and taking intersections of the $V$'s, relatively easily under the additional hypothesis of analyticity in the second variable.

I realize that this generalizes Hartog's theorem, so it is either false or hard to prove.

Comment: A little bit of nitpicking: I'm not sure I understand your example, $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ is surely continuous everywhere where it is defined which is $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\backslash\{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: @freakish As in the linked question, I extend it in the unique way that makes it separately continuous, by defining the value at the origin to be $0$.

Comment: Ah, right, that makes sense.