# The oscilation of $f$ at $x=0$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

The oscilation $o(f,x_{0})$ of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at a point $x_{0}$ is the infimum of the oscilations of the function $f(x)$ at each neighbourhood of the point $x_{0}$, where the oscilation at a set $U$, denoted by $o(f,U)$, is the difference $\sup_{x\in U}f(x)-\inf_{x\in U}f(x)$.

Suppose that $f(x)$ has a oscilation $o(f,x)=1$ at each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with $x\neq 0$. Which are the possible value of the oscilation of $f$ at $x=0$?.

*Attempt of proof:* I have considered the following neighbourhoods:

- $B(\frac{1}{2^{n}},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})$, the ball with center at $\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ and radius $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$.
- $B(0,\frac{1}{2^{n}})$, the ball with center at $0$ and radius $\frac{1}{2^{n}}$.

Then we have that $B(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},\frac{1}{2^{n}})\subset B(\frac{1}{2^{n}},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})$, and this implies that $1 \leq o(f,B(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},\frac{1}{2^{n}}))\leq o(f,B(\frac{1}{2^{n}},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}))$. Due to this inequality we have that the limit $lim_{n\to \infty} o(f,B(\frac{1}{2^{n}},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})))$ exists, and shall call it $\alpha$.  Observe that $1 \leq \alpha$.

On the other $B(0,\frac{1}{2^{n}})\subset B(\frac{1}{2^{n}},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})$, so $0\leq o(f,B(0,\frac{1}{2^{n}}))\leq o(f,B(\frac{1}{2^{n}},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}))$. Taking limit as $n\to \infty$ we have

$0\leq o(f,0) \leq \alpha$

Remark. This is an estimation of the range of values that $o(f,0)$ can take, but  I am not sure that this solve the problem.

Comment: This argument is not going in the right direction.  It is always true that $o (f,0) \geqslant 0$.  That does not mean it is in an interval $[0,\alpha]$ where $\alpha < 1$. The term $o(f,o(f,B(\frac{1}{2^{n}},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})))$ has no meaning.

Comment: @RRL. There was a mistake. It has been edited.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  But you have not solved the problem. We must have the oscillation at 0 at least $1$. I showed this in two different ways.

Comment: Yes that is a concrete answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $x \mapsto o(f,x)$ is upper semi-continuous, proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2256516/148510),  so $\{x:o(f,x) < \alpha\}$ is open for any $\alpha$. Thus it is impossible that $o(f,0) < 1$ since the oscillation equals $1$ in every punctured neighborhood of $x =0$. The set $\{x:o(f,x) <1\} = \{0\}$ is not open.

We can also argue directly using the fact that if $A \subset B$ then $o(f,A) \leqslant o(f,B)$. Take any interval $I_\delta= (-\delta,\delta)$. For any $x \neq 0$ in $I_\delta$, take $\delta_1$ such that $I_1 =(x- \delta_1,x+\delta_1) \subset (-\delta,\delta)$. We then have

$$1 = o(f,x) \leqslant \sup_{u,v \in I_1}|f(u) - f(v)| \leqslant \sup_{u,v \in I_\delta}|f(u) - f(v)| $$

Thus,

$$o(f,0) = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \sup_{u,v \in I_\delta}|f(u) - f(v)|\geqslant 1$$

Can we have $o(f,0) > 1$?  Yes -- for example take $f(0) =2 $ and $f$ taking values of $1$ and $0$ at all other rational points and irrational points in $[-1,1]$, respectively.